# Use doctrine in entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

how can i get doctrine in entity to get permission list?

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User implements UserInterface 
{
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $discordId;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180)
     */
    private $username;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Sites::class, mappedBy="owner", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $sites;

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     * @ORM\PostPersist
     */
    public function fetchEntityManager(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sites = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getdiscordId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->discordId;
    }
    public function setdiscordId(string $discordId): self
    {
        $this->discordId = $discordId;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getUsername(): ?string
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }
    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->username;
    }

    public function getRoles() :array
    {
        // get permissions from group
        $groupPermissionsRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(GroupPermissions::class);
        $groupAccessList = $groupPermissionsRepo->getPermissionsForGroup($this->getGroupId());

        // create access
        $accessList = [];
        foreach ($groupAccessList as $access) {
            $accessList[] = new Role('ROLE_'.$access);
        }

        // set default role when group didn't have any access granted
        if(count($groupAccessList) == 0)
            $accessList[] = new Role('ROLE_USER');

        // return access
        return $accessList;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Sites>
     */
    public function getSites(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sites;
    }

    public function addSite(Sites $site): self
    {
        if (!$this->sites->contains($site)) {
            $this->sites[] = $site;
            $site->setOwner($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSite(Sites $site): self
    {
        if ($this->sites->removeElement($site)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($site->getOwner() === $this) {
                $site->setOwner(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

While using this code i get only error:

App\Entity\User::fetchEntityManager(): Argument #1 ($args) must be of type Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\dbshop2\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Event\ListenersInvoker.php on line 84

Comment: Start with tweaking your use statement: `use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;` like the error message indicates.  Be aware that while this sort of thing can work it's usually not a good idea to have services in entities.  Might be better to just figure out the roles and set them.

Comment: The method `getGroupId()` is not defined. Why the roles are stored as JSON? Why your relations are not normalized? An entity never ever should have any logic as being a data object with an identifier. A many to many relation user:roles and roles:permissions and the logic on creating and updating a users roles in the repository would be the better way.

Comment: @Marcel Just for info, storing roles as a json array when using the Symfony authorization system is the standard default approach.  In most cases there is no need for the overhead of using a separate table.  The code in this question is a bit iffy.

Comment: Woah ... didn 't believe this at the first read and had to read the docs. Thanks for the hint. The link for everyone: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
Normalization should not be recognized as overhead. It 's always the cleanest approach. The symfony default approach seems to be a bit to much "standard". Never the less ... @Cerad mentioned the solution already. The type hint seems to be wrong.